# Windows and Ubuntu

Tags: dual-boot, windows

I want to know if when I install Ubuntu and keep Windows I can Delete windows later.

My English is not the best one, so I´ll be grateful is you use easy words.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it can be done with `gparted` program. When you install Ubuntu,  it divides hard drive into chunks or partitions. So you would need to boot from USB or CD and delete Windows partition.  (why usb because it dangerous to operate on a running disk).

On Ubuntu partition you will have a thing called `grub bootloader`. That this is what actually helps you choose between windows or Ubuntu when you start the computer.  If you just delete windows from computer that thing may break. So you will need to install it differently.  For example , if my Ubuntu is on `/dev/sda3`, I need to move grub to `/dev/sda`.

That's about it. Also with Windows 8 you'd need to disable safe boot feature to successfully install Ubuntu.